# Limit number of lines able to write with textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I want to not just limit the number of times enter can be pressed in the text area but stop the output being over two lines. To better explain, I have a photo frame designer [here](http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame2). In the options you can enter text and it will appear on the frame. Currently if you try to press enter in text area more than 2 times it won't let you. The problem arises when the text is too long and it automatically wraps to a new line.

Here is some relevant code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    var lines = 2;
    var linesUsed = $('#linesUsed');

    $('#input').keydown(function(e) {
        newLines = $(this).val().split("\n").length;
        linesUsed.text(newLines);
        if(e.keyCode == 13 && newLines >= lines) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

That's some jquery that limits the number of lines in the TEXTAREA.

And the textarea

```
<textarea id="input" maxlength="40" name="Text" value="Max. 40 characters"></textarea>
```

The jquery that prints the input from the text area

```
$('#input').keyup(function() {
    $('#text').html($(this).val());
});
```

This is the embedded html in my svg where the typed text is printed to.

```
<foreignObject x="135" y="520" width="600" height="260" style="color:white;text-align:center">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <div id="container2">
            <p id="text">Your words here</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</foreignObject>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic line wrapping in a textarea can be prevented using the attribute `wrap=off`, which is nonstandard but widely supported since the early days of HTML.

```html
<textarea id="input" maxlength="40" name="Text"
placeholder="Max. 40 characters" wrap="off"></textarea>
```

(I have changed the `value` attribute to a `placeholder` attribute. The `value` attribute is not valid for `textarea`.)

A different, possibly better approach is to avoid the problem by using two `input type=text` fields instead of one `textarea` field. Then you would not need JavaScript for preventing the entry of more than two lines, but if a limit on the total number of characters (instead of just setting a limit on each line) is needed, you would need simple JavaScript for that.

Comment: Ahh I see. Yeah the placeholder improves it thanks. I'd rather not use the inputs. Seems easier to do the JavaScript. But thanks didn't know about the wrap attribute.

Answer (score -3):

Here are 2 javascript libraries that can help you with this:

- [Stop Verbosity](http://williamhuey.github.io/code/stopverbosity/)
- [Limit](http://www.unwrongest.com/projects/limit/)

As you can see on the demo-sites, both these solutions just work.

Comment: So what? If it works, it works… It isn't as if the textarea element has radically changed over the last 3 years.

Comment: with version 1.4 of jquery it does, but it may not have been tested with any version since then